# How can I run a powershell script in a for loop?

Tags: powershell

I have been tasked to sort home video and pictures for my family. The scripts that I have work fine but I have to manually run them against each directory. How can I run my script against all child-items that are only at 1 Depth?

My current crude scripts are as follows:

```
$current_dir = Split-Path -Path $pwd -Leaf
$new_path = "H:\sorted\$current_dir\pictures"

Get-ChildItem -R . -Include ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png') | Move-Item -Destination (New-Item -Force -Path "$new_path" -Type Directory)
```

```
$current_dir = Split-Path -Path $pwd -Leaf
$new_path = "H:\sorted\$current_dir\videos"

Get-ChildItem -R . -Include ('*.mp4', '*.mkv', '*.3pg','*.flv', '*.mov', '*.gif') | Move-Item -Destination (New-Item -Force -Path "$new_path" -Type Directory)
```

Example file tree

```
E:.
├───April9383
├───April98765
│   └───carson
├───Cathy
├───Cathy(1)
├───Charlie
│   ├───Photos
│   └───Videos
├───daleville
```

I want the end structure to look like Charlie does in the example. How can I run both of these with a loop from E: ?

I have tried

```
$sub_dir = $(Get-ChildItem . -Depth 1)

foreach ($sub in $sub_dir)  {
    picture-sort.ps1
}
```

but this took the name of the folder that all of the example files were stored in and not that of "April9383" etc

SOLVED:

I ended up going with @Santiago's response but edited a bit as it wasn't working exactly how I needed it.

I took this and ran with it to end up with

```
$base = "E:\sorted"
$current_dir = $pwd
# get the folders 1 level deep and enumerate
Get-ChildItem . -Depth 0 -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # join the destination with this folder's Name
    $path = Join-Path $base -ChildPath $_.Name
    $pic_path = "$path\pictures"
    $vid_path = "$path\videos"
    
    #source dirs
    $stripped_dest_path = Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf
    $src_path = Join-Path $current_dir  $stripped_dest_path 
    
    #Print statement
    Write-Output "Copying pictures from $src_path to $pic_path"
    # get and move all pictures
    Get-ChildItem -R $src_path -Include ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png') |
        Copy-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Destination (New-Item -Force -Path "$pic_path" -Type Directory)

    #Print statement
    Write-Output "Copying videos from $src_path to $vid_path"
    # get and move all videos
    Get-ChildItem -R $src_path -Include ('*.mp4', '*.mkv', '*.3pg','*.flv', '*.mov', '*.gif', '*.avi') |
        Copy-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Destination (New-Item -Force -Path "$vid_path" -Type Directory)


    Write-Output "END OF LOOP"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, just need to put all your logic inside the loop:

```
$base = "H:\sorted"
# get the folders 1 level deep and enumerate
Get-ChildItem . -Depth 1 -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # join the destination with this folder's Name
    $path = Join-Path $base -ChildPath $_.Name

    # get and move all pictures
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png' |
        Move-Item -Destination (New-Item -Path (Join-Path $path -ChildPath 'Pictures') -Type Directory -Force)

    # get and move all videos
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include '*.mp4', '*.mkv', '*.3pg','*.flv', '*.mov', '*.gif' |
        Move-Item -Destination (New-Item -Path (Join-Path $path -ChildPath 'videos') -Type Directory -Force)
}
```

Comment: Thanks this somewhat worked but I had to remove `$_ | ` from both picture and video lines or else it added everything to the pictures folder including old, empty directories from the source.

edit: nevermind, this is just adding copies to everything in the new folders that are created

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with @Santiago's response but edited a bit as it wasn't working exactly how I needed it.

I took this and ran with it to end up with

```
$base = "E:\sorted"
$current_dir = $pwd
# get the folders 1 level deep and enumerate
Get-ChildItem . -Depth 0 -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # join the destination with this folder's Name
    $path = Join-Path $base -ChildPath $_.Name
    $pic_path = "$path\pictures"
    $vid_path = "$path\videos"
    
    #source dirs
    $stripped_dest_path = Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf
    $src_path = Join-Path $current_dir  $stripped_dest_path 
    
    #Print statement
    Write-Output "Copying pictures from $src_path to $pic_path"
    # get and move all pictures
    Get-ChildItem -R $src_path -Include ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png') |
        Copy-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Destination (New-Item -Force -Path "$pic_path" -Type Directory)

    #Print statement
    Write-Output "Copying videos from $src_path to $vid_path"
    # get and move all videos
    Get-ChildItem -R $src_path -Include ('*.mp4', '*.mkv', '*.3pg','*.flv', '*.mov', '*.gif', '*.avi') |
        Copy-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Destination (New-Item -Force -Path "$vid_path" -Type Directory)


    Write-Output "END OF LOOP"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$PictureFiles = @('*.jpg', '*.png')
$VideoFiles = @('*.mkv', '*.mp4')

$MyFiles = Get-ChildItem H:\sorted -Recurse -File -Include @($PictureFiles + $VideoFiles) -Depth 1

foreach ($File in $MyFiles) {
    #Videos
    if ($File.Extension -in ($VideoFiles -replace '\*')) {
        mkdir ($File.DirectoryName + "\Videos\") -Force
        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination ($File.DirectoryName + "\Videos\" + $File.Name) -Force
    }

    #Pictures
    if ($File.Extension -in ($PictureFiles -replace '\*')) {
        mkdir ($File.DirectoryName + "\Pictures\") -Force
        Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination ($File.DirectoryName + "\Pictures\" + $File.Name) -Force
    }
}
```